# Pandas: Parsing column labels to datetime index

Tags: pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe set up as follows, `df_in`. I need to have an output, `df_out`, with temporal periods parsed from the column labels in `df_in`set up as datetime index and values for common activities (`'Act_1'`, `'Act_2'`) grouped in corresponding series.

Question is how to achieve this?

`df_in`:

```
Index    Act_1 (Dec-20-Jan-21)    Act_1 (Jan-21-Feb-21)    Act_1 (Feb-21-Mar-21)     Act_2 (Dec-20-Jan-21)    Act_2 (Jan-21-Feb-21)    Act_2 (Feb-21-Mar-21) 
0        20                       30                       10                        A                        B                        C
```

`df_out`:

```
Index        Act_1    Act_2
Feb/2021     10       C
Jan/2021     30       B
Dec/2020     20       A
```

Any pointers and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `transpose` your data, use `Series.str.extract` to obtain Act and Date, and finally `pivot`:

```
df = df.T.reset_index()

pat = "(?P<Act>Act_\d+)\s\((?P<Date>[A-Za-z]{3}\-\d{2})"

print (pd.concat([df, df["index"].str.extract(pat)], axis=1)
         .pivot("Date", "Act", 0))

Act    Act_1 Act_2
Date              
Dec-20    20     A
Feb-21    10     C
Jan-21    30     B
```